Unity VR UI canvas popup
How can I open a UI canvas panel when an object is clicked by VR controller in Unity VR? I want to implement this functionality where clicking on an object in a Unity VR environment triggers the opening of a UI panel. How can I achieve this? If you have any insights or suggestions
open panel on object click in unity VR

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
